# teamcity test never fails

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, teamcity

I am implementing a Powershell build script for teamcity to test some functionality, but cannot figure out out to report an error.

I am trying to follow this description:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingTests

However, although the script actually results in some tests being registered, it refuses to report errors. I am now back to the basic example from the . I have the following Powershell build step (error output: error, script: source):

```
Write-Host("##teamcity[testStarted name='className.testName']")
Write-Host("##teamcity[testStdErr name='className.testName' out='error text']")
Write-Host("##teamcity[testFinished name='className.testName']")
```

Resulting build log (verbose):

```
[13:27:12]Step 1/5: Output to build log (Powershell)
[13:27:13][Step 1/5] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:firstStepPreparation' value='156.0']
[13:27:13][Step 1/5] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_18' value='0.0']
[13:27:13][Step 1/5] Starting:   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command - <  D:\JetBrains\buildagent\temp\buildTmp\powershell6640337654487221076.ps1
[13:27:13][Step 1/5] in directory: D:\JetBrains\buildagent\work\7e3fac8e390ca38d

[13:27:13][Step 1/5] className.testName
[13:27:13][className.testName] [Test Error Output] error text

[13:27:13][Step 1/5] Process exited with code 0
[13:27:13][Step 1/5] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_18' value='536.0']
```

I.e. the test is registered in teamcity as executed bit it succeeds! I would expect the test to fail, due to the 'testStdErr' output! What it the correct way to make it fail?

Thanks,
Kim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `testFailed` directive which is listed on the page you linked:

```
##teamcity[testFailed name='MyTest.test1' message='failure message' details='message and stack trace']
```

Or change the build failure condition settings under 'Build Failure Conditions' to fail the build if you write to stderr (**edit:** this is my understand of the docs anyway):

```
Fail build if:
[ ] an error message is logged by build runner
```